# Entire Site Responsive But Can Still Scroll To Right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on http://preview.j64e7zzvo82p4x6r4fdjze6piimmfgviwsruf9j89pidaemi.box.codeanywhere.com/ and have nearly finished making it responsive.

But for some reason when the browser is sized to anything below 991px in width then it creates whitespace on the right side. All of the content will snap to the screen size but at the end of the day you can still scroll to the right and see a big black background because of all the whitespace.

I thought it was the images on the size that were to big for the viewport but even after removing the images, adding the img-responsive class to the images, and other attempts to fix, the site still has this problem

What is causing all of this whitespace?

Comment: Easy way: `body { overflow-x: hidden; }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this fixed it for me - you are missing the viewport code from what I can see - for example:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

You can read more at - the third paragraph down http://getbootstrap.com/css/

edited, actually I must have tried that while you applied you fix... I'd still put the viewport in though!...

Comment: I've just copied your code to my desktop - added the viewport - this image is one of the culprits for me /images/store_bg.png - it's breaking the width - adding max-width:100%; to that image cured part of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The rule for `#ctaButtons` has a fixed width. Try replace it to `auto`:

```
#ctaButtons {
  width: auto;
  height: 120px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: a % could also be considered

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `overflow-x: hidden;` to your container `<div>`.

Comment: doesn't actually fix the problem in the inspector - overflow hidden on a container div is probably a bit too much, finding the offending element and editing it would be prefered